# Is there any risk if my Google Analytics cookies can be seen by an attacker?

Tags: cookies

In particular, I'm concerned about a scenario where I'm using GA cookies on a subdomain, e.g. `alice.example.com`, and the cookies are marked as `.example.com`, which means that a site on `eve.example.com` can see them.

Can Eve do anything malicious with that information?

I [found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284384/8446), but I'd like to understand if there are any security/privacy risks.